# Flexbox stretching and aligning elements (on second row and on different screen)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have this flexbox (picture 1). 
[image]

But I need to stretch the sixth element to the containers full width (picture 2).

[image]

I've tried align-items and align-content: stretch; but it didn't work.

I also would like the sixth element to take the full width when the width is 1225 (like picture 4), but currently it looks like this (picture 3).

[image]
[image]

I tried changing the display when the width changes to 1225px (using `@media(min-width: 1225px)`), but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Can someone please exlain how can I achieve this ? What styles should I be using and why ? I'm new to flexbox.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <section id="one">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-five">5.1</div>
        <div class="item-five">5.2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-six-main">
        <div class="item-six">6.1</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.2</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.3</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.4</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.5</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.6</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.7</div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(209, 253, 138);
}

@media(min-width: 1225px) {
  #one {
    background-color: rgb(40, 255, 51);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

#one {
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: rgb(180, 153, 255);
  height: 500px;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: bisque;
  flex-basis: 20%;

}

.item-five {
  background-color: rgb(245, 101, 173);
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50%;
}

.item-six-main {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.item-six {
  background-color: rgb(131, 250, 230);
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Here is the entire thing on **jsfiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/mg6zwm3L/5/

Comment: i Don't have access to images, could you tell me what you want ? I have your fiddle, and if I got it, you want the sixth element to have its own line ?

Comment: There are no images, I just used background-color, just like on the jsfiddle. I would like the sixth element to be just like picture 2, and then when it shrinks bellow 1225px, I want it to be like picture 4. If that means that I must put it in a new row, then yes I guess.

Comment: No I meant on SOF, I don't have access to imgur so I don't see your images ... So could you explain your pictures on SOF with words ? "Like picture 2" doesn't work with me :/

Comment: Aha okay. I need the sixth element to stretch full width of the container. So it should go from the fifth element to the end of the page. Right now it's just at the right of the page, there is a gap in the middle.

Comment: each flex-item has flex-grow set to 1 which means each will take equal space but if any flex-item has flex-grow: 0, it will stop this item from expanding unnecessarily and other item with flex-grow:1 will take up the rest of the space.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `flex: 1` to the target items? This tells the items to consume all available space. https://jsfiddle.net/mg6zwm3L/12/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using stretch. Try flex-grow:1. It will grow them evenly inside the div.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(209, 253, 138);
}

@media(min-width: 1225px) {
  #one {
    background-color: rgb(40, 255, 51);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

#one {
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-color: rgb(180, 153, 255);
  height: 500px;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: bisque;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  
}

.item-five {
  background-color: rgb(245, 101, 173);
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50%;
}

.item-six-main {
  background-color: red;
 display: flex;
  min-width: 70%;
}

.item-six {
  background-color: rgb(131, 250, 230);
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
   

  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>SecondTask</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section id="one">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-five">5.1</div>
        <div class="item-five">5.2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-six-main">
        <div class="item-six">6.1</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.2</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.3</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.4</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.5</div>
        <div class="item-six">6.6</div>
   
   
    </section> -->
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just set my fifth element `flex-grow: 1` and my sixth element `flex-grow: 5` .Thank Naomi

Comment: @IkePr wut? that's not a solution, check how the items allign in weird places when the last div wraps into a line on his own

Answer (score 0):

After my comment and your answer, here is mine :

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/urforovg/)

When you want a container to take the remaining space, you simply need to give him a flex property like so :

```
.item-six-main {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

the `flex: 1 1 auto;` is a shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.

This one means

> Grow like every other component would grow, shrink like every other component would shrink, and take all the remaining space in your container.

You can find [**more information about flexboxes here**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: you probably don't know this as you have no access to the images, but it seems he also needs "margins" on the last row to align with the first. So flexbox is not the way.

Comment: Well there's no way to do that, you can only align items having the same size at a given time. If you want your items to be aligned, then you need to set the margins and not the sizes of your items.

Comment: Please show me how you align 3 items with 100px width, and 2 items with 156px and 472px. I am very curious about what a grid can do that flexboxes can't.